# How to find and replace these HTML sentences using grep and perl/sed

Tags: regex, perl, sed, grep

I've lines of HTML that contains newlines and stuffs, I want to replace a sentence like this :

```
<li class="menu-581"><a href="../you-your-me-nm.html" title="You &amp;amp;
">You &amp; Your Service Dog</a></li>
```

notice the newline before `">You`

I have the first part, of finding the snippet

```
pcregrep  -r -M -l '<li class="menu-581">(.|\n)*?</li>' *
```

Now , I want to feed it into Perl to replace the same regex with new text

I'm trying this perl snippet but it doesnt work (i'm saving it in a file called test.txt):

```
ls test.* | xargs perl -pe 's/<li class="menu-581">(.|\n)*<\/li>/new/' -pi
```

Any clue?

Comment: as per usual: don't use regexes on html. use a DOM parser. it'll make your life a lot easier.

Comment: @MarcB its a one time task, so it is ok

Comment: @Naughty.Coder: No, it's never okay to do things wrongly

Comment: Why tag it with `sed` if you're looking for a perl solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** This one I've actually tested, so it is working as expected:

```
 ls test.* | xargs perl -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;};s/(<li class="menu-581">)(.*)(<\/li>)/$1$3/gs'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cat -e test.html
```

```
<p>$
<li class="menu-581"><a href="../you-your-me-nm.html" title="You &amp;amp;$
">You &amp; Your Service Dog</a></li>$
</p>$
```

Then

```
perl -0777 -pe 's{\Q<li class="menu-581"><a href="../you-your-me-nm.html" title="You &amp;amp;
">You &amp; Your Service Dog</a></li>}{}g' test.html
```

```
<p>

</p>
```

Add the `-i` flag to edit in-place:

```
perl -0777 -i -pe '...' test*
```